# Angular 2 Routes - Is it possible to create dynamic routerLinks from routes, using an ngFor?

Tags: javascript, angular, routes, angular2-routing

I would like to take all of the Routes in a specific module that have a defined path, and use ngFor to loop through them and create a dynamic list of links in my component html.

ngFor Example (overview.component.html):

```
<li *ngFor="let item of items; let i = index;">
   <a routerLink="/{route.path}">{route.path}</a>
</li>
```

module example (base.module.ts):

```
...

const routerConfig = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: BaseComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        component: OverviewComponent
      },
      {
        path: 'group-one',
        component: OverviewComponent
      },
      {
        path: 'group-one/:id',
        component: DetailComponent
      },
      {
        path: 'group-two',
        component: OverviewComponent
      },
      {
        path: 'group-two/:id',
        component: DetailComponent
      }
    ]
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forChild(routerConfig)
  ]
  ...
})
export class BaseModule { }
```

After trying various experiments with ActivatedRoute, Router, etc, I have not been able to find an object where this information is made available to use.

Is this currently possible via the Angular 2 Router?

How could I go about solving this problem?

Comment: Maybe [router.config](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/index/Router-class.html#!#config-anchor) could helps. You could play with this.

Comment: @developer033 a loop through router.config[i].path does list all of the top level routes, but not ones specific to a nested module. You would think that this would be accessible via ActivatedRoute somewhere...

Comment: Have you tried `console.log(this.activatedRoute.routeConfig)`?

Comment: well son of a... it's showing up now under "children". Perhaps initially I was not using the children container when I first tested this. Graci for your reply.

Answer (score 3):

This code

```
<a routerLink="/{route.path}">
```

passes `/{route.path}` literally as route path

You probably either want

```
<a [routerLink]="'/' + route.path">
```

or

```
<a routerLink="/{{route.path}}">
```

For Angular to evaluate expressions, bindings need to have exactly one of `[]` or `{{}}` (never both at the same time)

```
[propName]="..."
```

or

```
propName="{{...}}"
```

The later always stringifies the result and is therefore not suitable to pass objects.